# Magento 2.3.4 Command "show" failed: In RemoteFilesystem.php line 742:

Tags: magento2.3.4

This error shows when I hit Extension manager in the Magento Admin. How do I fix it?

```
Command "show" failed: In RemoteFilesystem.php line 742: The 'https://repo.wyomind.com/packages.json' URL required authentication. You must be using the interactive console to authenticate show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [-l|--latest] [-o|--outdated] [--ignore IGNORE] [-m|--minor-only] [-D|--direct] [--strict] [-f|--format FORMAT] [--] [<package> [<version>]]
```

Comment: check this answer :--- https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Corrupt-extention-manager-after-installing-Amasty-Extention/m-p/89950/highlight/true#M3731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating composer.json with the credentials for the extension, in my case, by Wyomind fixed the issue. Pasting the code below in case someone else ever encounters the similar issue.

```
    "repo-name": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://user_name:I}XRJiL=@repo.wyomind.com"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with access to wyomind's repository. You can solve this issue by finding and removing "wyomind" node from your composer.json file located at your Magento installation's root and running `composer update` command.

**EDIT**

You can also unset the repository's config using `composer config --unset repositories.wyomind` , the next time you try to install any wyomind extension via composer, it will ask for updated public and private key.

Comment: I had installed a couple of extensions by Wyomind. Does removing Wyoming node from the composer.json make these extension non-functional?

Comment: hmm, I though it may be remnants of broken installations, if you've installed the extension check the edit in the answer.

Comment: I get the same error even after running `composer config --unset repositories.wyomind`. Should anything else have been done?

Comment: have you run the command from magento's root foider?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: When I contacted the Wyomind, I was asked to update the credentials for Wyomind in the composer.json. Any suggestion around this?

Comment: My command would have removed the authentication and asked for it when you ran another composer command so you would not have to look for auth.json. But you can also look for auth.json in your installation and try to find node "repo.wyomind.com" or something similar and update your public and private key there.

Comment: you can also try running composer update without looking for auth.json too.

Comment: I would like to try updating auth.json, Could you please mention the location of this file in Magento?3

Comment: It's usually located at magento's root.

Comment: I don't find it. Do I need to create one if it is not present?

Comment: Is it okay remove this entry from the composer? `        "wyomind": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.wyomind.com"
        },
        "repo-name": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.wyomind.com"
        }`

Comment: you can try removing it, but please take the backup of Wyomind vendor folder in app/code as well as vendor folder

Comment: Neither did it work.